# Uploaded image is posted twice when choosing "from web"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, images, uploader

So this bug I tested on MSE and SO and SE network chatroom, and found out whenever I try to upload an image via the option "from the web" in chatroom, It is uploading the image two times and hence we can see two posts of same image. I think it should not happen. Because in case when upload an image via "from my computer", it works just fine.

[image]

The OS I am using is Windows 7 and Browser is chrome.

Comment: OS and browser, please?

Comment: Windows 7 and Chrome. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Not reproduced. I tried in multiple chat rooms and it works fine.

Comment: @NogShine of course, you don't have the userscript (lucky for you) that is buggy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tested this bug on other browsers, but it's not reproducible. So I tried disabling all extension one by one installed on my browser and turned out that an extension was causing this issue which is [SO Dark Chat +](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/so-dark-chat-%20/bbkjccfnenmgidehjhaabamobpbaaghh) created by [rLemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon).

Comment: Looks like it's from the image copy+paste implementation, most likely [this line](https://github.com/rlemon/se-chat-dark-theme-plus/blob/master/js/better_image_uploads.js#L77).

Comment: @Ben Cool! Should be easy fix now then.

Comment: Neat, I forgot that input was there (because why would you need it for image uploads with the feature enabled ;) ), but I'll take a look at it soon. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @rlemon np and Thanks :-)